# Angular check if user is coming from whatsapp

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angualar6 and want to find the source from where the user is coming.

Using `document.referrer` I get my previous URL and can check if it is Google or Facebook but with WhatsApp document.referrer is blank.

Is there any way to get to know from which source (FB, Whatsapp, Google, etc) the user is coming to my Angular site.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend might have a clue, but if WhatsApp is not setting any referral or your link does not contain an indicator it was shared through a certain medium like Whatsapp, there's no way to detect it as such.